# perform matrix multiplication to compute rotation in python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, rotation, matrix-multiplication

I have a bunch of image coordinates stored in a matrix of size `Nx2xHxW`. "N" means the number of images, "H" and "W" are short for height and width, and each `nx1xHxW` instance of this matrix stores the x and y coordinates of image n.

Applying rotation to a 2x1 vector V is done by creating a 2x2 rotation matrix R:

```
[[np.cos(theta), -np.sin(theta)],
 [np.sin(theta), np.sin(theta)]]
```

and performing matrix multiplication R * V, resulting in a new 2x1 vector.

Now I have a rotation matrix R with size `Nx2x2` and I'd like to apply the rotation computation to each instance of M. A straightforward approach is:

```
B = 8
N = 2
H = 100
W = 200
M = np.random.rand(B, N, H, W)
R = np.random.rand(B, N, N)

for i in range(B):
    tmp1 = R[i, 0, 0] * M[i, 0, :, :] + R[i, 0, 1] * M[i, 1, :, :]
    tmp2 = R[i, 1, 0] * M[i, 0, :, :] + R[i, 1, 1] * M[i, 1, :, :]
    M[i, 0, :, :] = tmp1
    M[i, 1, :, :] = tmp2
```

This is clearly very inefficient, I was wondering if there's a better way to perform such task in python.

Thanks!

Comment: look at np.matmul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be using `np.einsum`

```
>>> Mpp = np.einsum('ijk,iklm->ijlm', R, M)

#verify
>>> for i in range(B):
...     tmp1 = R[i, 0, 0] * M[i, 0, :, :] + R[i, 0, 1] * M[i, 1, :, :]
...     tmp2 = R[i, 1, 0] * M[i, 0, :, :] + R[i, 1, 1] * M[i, 1, :, :]
...     M[i, 0, :, :] = tmp1
...     M[i, 1, :, :] = tmp2
... 
>>> 
>>> np.allclose(Mpp, M)
True
```